# How to know the columns of gridview which has updated?

Tags: asp.net

I am working on gridview in c# using .net 2.0.I have requriement like, there is only one columns in gridview and 5 columns in that grid.
Edit/update option is there for grid.When i click on edit 4 columns are editable out of 5.
Now user update only 2 columns says like col2, col3 etc. 
Now i have to send email based on updated columns.

My problem is how to identify that only col2, col3 has updated.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using events like selectedrow then you can get cell id and cell values and by compering them to the old values in the datasource or dataset which so ever you can send mail.